# how to solve a image puzzle by numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

So the problem set is that there's an image of 360x360 pixels and the restore the scrambled images given in the test data to the original image(the original image has been divided into 9 pieces and randomly rearranged to form the scrambled image by the teacher beforehand), and I'm having trouble with solving the problem. 
(The clues given by the teacher are to minimize the difference between the pixels at the edge of the adjacent pieces to find the correct arrangement)

I have tried breaking the given image into the 9 correct pieces and using `itertools.permutation` to find all the possible cases of puzzle arrangements and minimizing the boundary differences to find the correct arrangement. but this seems to be not a good way because it requires a large number of calculations and storages of data, also, my current code was not able to output an answer. Can someone please tell me what to do next? Here's what I have written.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import itertools


def solve_puzzle(img):
    ret = img.copy()

    ret_ = []
    for i in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            ret_.append(ret[120*i:120*(i+1),120*k:120*(k+1),:])

    ret_per = itertools.permutations(ret_)

    def vertical_sum(r):
        k = 0.
        r0 = r[0]
        r1 = r[1]
        r2 = r[2]
        r3 = r[3]
        r4 = r[4]
        r5 = r[5]
        r6 = r[6]
        r7 = r[7]
        r8 = r[8]
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r1[i,0,:]-r0[i,119,:])
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r2[i,0,:]-r1[i,119,:])
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r4[i,0,:]-r3[i,119,:])
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r5[i,0,:]-r4[i,119,:])
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r7[i,0,:]-r6[i,119,:])
        for i in range(120):
            k += sum(r8[i,0,:]-r7[i,119,:])
        return k

    def horizontal_sum(r):
        p = 0.
        r0 = r[0]
        r1 = r[1]
        r2 = r[2]
        r3 = r[3]
        r4 = r[4]
        r5 = r[5]
        r6 = r[6]
        r7 = r[7]
        r8 = r[8]
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r3[0,i,:]-r0[119,i,:])
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r4[0,i,:]-r1[119,i,:])
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r5[0,i,:]-r2[119,i,:])
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r6[0,i,:]-r3[119,i,:])
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r7[0,i,:]-r4[119,i,:])
        for i in range(120):
            p += sum(r8[0,i,:]-r5[119,i,:])
        return p

    boundary = {}
    for i in ret_per:
        t = 0.
        t += vertical_sum(i) + horizontal_sum(i)
        boundary[t] = i

    find = boundary[min(boundary.keys())]

    ret[0:120,0:120,:] = find[0]
    ret[0:120,120:240,:] = find[1]
    ret[0:120,240:360,:] = find[2]
    ret[120:240,0:120,:] = find[3]
    ret[120:240,120:240,:] = find[4]
    ret[120:240,240:360,:] = find[5]
    ret[240:360,0:120,:] = find[6]
    ret[240:360,120:240,:] = find[7]
    ret[240:360,240:360,:] = find[8]

    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.load('jigsaw_data.npy')

    idx = np.random.randint(10)
    ret = solve_puzzle(data[idx])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=80)
    plt.imshow(ret)
    plt.show()
```

The output should be the correct [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkUp8.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like going through all permutations is going to be very time consuming.
I suggest that you take a piece and you compute the difference between the borders(TOP, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM) of the RGB values of the rest of the 8 pieces. The minimum difference between a single border of any two pieces should indicate that those pieces are most likely to be alongside one another in that specific direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have tried calculating the four borders minimum to locate the center piece and then use the center piece to locate the top piece. However, the results were inconsistent for different pictures. So I have asked the TA of the class, and he suggested that I keep working on finding the arrangement with the minimum total boundary difference and it should be comparable for python. Does anyone have any suggestion on another way to find all the possible puzzle arrangements? Because I think itertools.permutation is not a very efficient way